# Python multiple inheritance constructor not called when using super()

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = 'blue'
    def get_something(self):
        return self.something
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.get_something())
```

and then do:

```
c = C()
```

which results in something like this:

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'something'
```

I suppose this happens due to the constructor of B not being called when using super(). Is there a way to achieve the correct behavior with Python 3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Superclasses should use super if their subclasses do.  If you add the         `super().__init__()` line into A and B your example should work again.

Check the method resolution order of C:

```
>>> C.mro()
[__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, builtins.object]
```

[This article](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) should clear things up.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the method resolution order is key here. If you want to call multiple superclass constructors, then you can call them directly.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = 'blue'
    def get_something(self):
        return self.something
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        print(self.get_something())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As it seems though, just calling super() one more time is easier.

Comment: Your choice. I just wanted to show this option as well, since it is my preference.

Comment: This style of multiple inheritance breaks down if your inheritance hierarchy is more complex. For instance, if `A` and `B` both inherited from some common `Base` class (the classic "diamond" pattern) and both called `Base.__init__(self)` from their own `__init__` methods, the `Base` class would be initialized twice. If you used `super` instead, each `__init__` method would be called exactly once.

Comment: Hardcoding the base classes in the subclasses is definitely the wrong way to solve this.

Comment: The superclasses are already "hardcoded" into the class definition. Creating a dependence from a superclass to other peers is more damaging in my opinion.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson the right answer is to simply use super, and use it in every class.  Then all the initializers are called, no matter where they are.

Comment: What happens if one of your `__init__` methods *anywhere* takes arguments? Or what if you inherit from a class that exists in a package that you don't maintain?

Comment: If you need to accept arguments in a method that does collaborative multiple inheritance (using `super` calls), you should use keyword-only arguments and always accept `**kwargs` and pass it along in your super call, e.g.: `def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2, **kwargs): super().__init__(**kwargs)`. As long as each keyword argument is accepted in one of the implementations, you won't get any errors, nor will it be possible for an invalid call to pass without an exception. A subclass can also inspect and/or modify the args it passes to its base classes (by both accepting and passing them on).

Comment: That sort-of works if everyone does `__init__` that way, but even here we are not.

Comment: Well, collaborative multiple inheritance does require collaboration from all the base classes, that's true. You can relax the rules a bit from what I described above (especially the keyword-only part) and still get a workable system. It's also possible to have a class with some methods that support collaborative multiple inheritance while others only support a simpler inheritance model. Its up to you to determine how much multiple inheritance is worth in your code. Using `super()` is easy though, and is really a best practice for every program.